# Calculating improper integral $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Calculate improper integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$

We had the following equation to calculate improper integrals (2nd style):
Let f in$\left(a,b\right]$ unbounded, but $\forall \varepsilon >0$ in every subinterval $\left[a+\varepsilon,b\right]$ is bounded, we define:

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\,dx:=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\displaystyle \int_{a+\varepsilon}^b f(x)\, dx$

However, I only came up with this solution:
\begin{align}
&\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx &&\ \mid \ u=\arcsin x \to dx=\sqrt{1-x^2}\, du\quad u=\arcsin0=0 \quad u=\arcsin1=\pi/2\\
&=\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac\pi2}u\,du\\
&= \left[\frac{u^2}{2}\right]^{\frac\pi2}_0\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}
My question is now, which is more accurate (and is this even correct)?

Comment: Its one, I'm sorry.

Comment: What you did at the end is fine, because the substitution is correct and thus the improper integral becomes a proper Riemann one.

Comment: I would also have done this integral this way, very well ;)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Technically you have to rewrite your improper integral as a limit, then make the substitution. Since everything in sight is continuous though, it works out to be the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the "improperness" occurs at $x=1.$ So you should let $0<b<1$ and consider

$$\int_0^b\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx,$$
 then take the limit as $b\to 1^-.$ This will lead to the answer you found.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you show only one solution, because the first approach remains theoretical. The only way that I know to handle this integral is by the arc sine change of variable, which makes the "improperness" disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't at $x=0$, but instead at $x=1$.
However, your substitution seems to have eliminated this issue, so yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$I\;=\;\lim_{b \to 1} \int_{0}^{b} \frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
Let $$u\;=\;\arcsin x$$
Then $$du\;=\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
We have $$I\;=\;\lim_{b \to 1} \int_{0}^{b} (\arcsin x) \,d(\arcsin x)$$
$$=\;\lim_{b \to 1}\frac{1}{2}\arcsin^2x \Big\lvert_{0}^b\;=\;\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Comment: Please add words to explain how arrived at this.  Certainly, we can not expect any student to accept someone's assertion at face value.